# List of Defined Variables AND Values in R

Tags: r

I have an R script, which calculates lots of variables. I am using Linux and console only.

How can I print all variables and their values

- a) to the terminal output
- b) to a pdf file
- c) to a text file

I would prefer the following structure for the output (if possible):

```
var_1 = value1
var_2 = value2
...
```

PS: ls() is only showing variable names and I was unable to find a solution after searching for 30mins...

Comment: Try `mget(ls())`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get()` with `lapply()`

```
   lapply(ls(), function(x) get(x))
```

To get it with variable names use `unlist()`

```
   setNames(lapply(ls(), function(x) get(x)), unlist(ls()))
```

Use `sink()` to write it out

```
   sink("Variables.txt")
   setNames(lapply(ls(), function(x) get(x)), unlist(ls()))
   sink()
```

Comment: shows correct values but without variable names... instead there is [[1]] and [[2]] and so on...

Comment: Nice, but it still ends up like this: `$x (linebreak)
[1] 14 (linebreak)
(linebreak)
$x_a (linebreak)
[1] 15.10143 (linebreak)` ... I would prefer `$x = 14 (linebreak)`